Reference heading not appearing in Table of contents
I am struggling with a bug of references.I am able to cite reference but the refernces cheading is not appearing in my table of contents.I am sharing my code file to have look over
\documentclass[
    oneside, 
    fontsize=12pt,          
    paper=a4,               
    numbers=noenddot,      
    listof=totoc,          
    listof=entryprefix,     
    listof=nochaptergap,    
    parskip=half            
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=numeric
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\addbibresource{Ref.bib}
\usepackage{geometry}  
    left=2.5cm,     
    right=2.5cm,    
    top=2.5cm,      
    bottom=2.5cm,   
}

\input{preamble}  
% load preamble


\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}} 
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}  
  {\chaptername\ \thechapter} 
  {5pt}                     
  {\Large}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {\thesection}
  {5pt}
  {}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}
  {\thesubsection}
  {5pt}
  {}
\begin{document}

\include{framework/titlepage}           % title page

% Roman numbering
\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\include{Abstract}
\tableofcontents


% Content
\mainmatter

\include{framework/Introduction}
\include{framework/overview}
\include{framework/Modustoolbox}
\include{framework/Acquiring Data}
\include{framework/Conclusions and Future applications}



\nocite{r1}
\nocite{r2}
\nocite{r3}
\nocite{r4}
\nocite{r5}
\printbibliography[title={References}]

\end{document}


Your example is unfortunately not complete. and does not compile due to mistakes. However, try for example class option bibliography=totoc. See the KOMA-Script manual for more information. Alternatively read the biblatex manual for other options.

Maybe unrelated to the problem: Note also all the warnings in the log file, because of not recommended or not supported combinations of packages with KOMA-Script classes.

Especially the KOMA-Script specific answer or the biblatex specific answer to the recommended question.

Please don't change a question into a completely different one. If you have another question, you should ask a new question instead. And also note the links in my first comment. Without MWE, it is almost impossible to answer your new question.

Thank you very much
